# How to ask the user for an output file in python

Tags: python, append, user-input, file-io

I have to ask the user for an output file and then append data to it but whenever I try it tells me that the data has no append attribute. I think this is because when I try to open the file it is seeing it as a string and not an actual file to append data too. I have tried multiple ways of doing this but right now I am left with this:

```
Output_File = str(raw_input("Where would you like to save this data? "))
fileObject = open(Output_File, "a")
fileObject.append(Output, '\n')
fileObject.close()
```

The output that I am trying to append to it is just a list I earlier defined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want the list written one item per line with a newline at the end it is `fileObject.write('%s\n' % '\n'.join(str(item) for item in Output))` if you want it comma separated but without the brackets it is `fileObject.write('%s\n' % ', '.join(str(item) for item in Output))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is at this line:

```
fileObject.append(Output, '\n')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Use the write method of a file object:

```
fileObject.write(Output+'\n')
```

Comment: "The output that I am trying to append to it is just a list I earlier defined." You need to turn that list into a string, too.

Comment: @agf, yea, I saw that, but it did not jive with the posted code snippet at all.  I took it to mean that they are "listing" things in a file.

Answer (score 2):

File objects have no `append` method. You're looking for `write`. Also, `str(raw_input(...))` is redundant, `raw_input` already returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory. This is because file objects don't have `append` method. You should simply use `write`:

```
fileObject.write(str(Output) + '\n')
```

Comment: "The output that I am trying to append to it is just a list I earlier defined." List -> string also necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    Output = [1,2,4,4]
    Output_File = input("Where would you like to save this data?")
    fileObject = open(Output_File, 'a')
    fileObject.write(str(Output)+'\n')
    fileObject.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

just use the .write method.

Comment: no need for `seek`, the file is already opened in append mode